# Jcenter (Bintray) not approving android library

Tags: android, android-library, bintray, jcenter, jfrog-cli

I made an android library (my first one)..
followed the steps and was able to successfully upload to bintray..but when i requested to link to jCenter ,I got this mail from Bintray:

> Please consolidate all necessary files e.g. pom, aar and sources into one common path and we will gladly approve your inclusion request.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here's my bintray libary https://bintray.com/hitanshu-dhawan/maven/SharedPref

my libary build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 1
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

ext {
    bintrayRepo = 'maven'
    bintrayName = 'SharedPref'
    publishedGroupId = 'com.hitanshudhawan.sharedpref'
    libraryName = 'sharedpref'
    artifact = 'sharedpref'
    libraryDescription = 'An android library for making SharedPreferences easy'
    siteUrl = 'https://github.com/hitanshu-dhawan/SharedPref'
    gitUrl = 'https://github.com/hitanshu-dhawan/SharedPref.git'
    libraryVersion = '1.0.0'
    developerId = 'hitanshu-dhawan'
    developerName = 'Hitanshu Dhawan'
    developerEmail = 'hitanshudhawan1996@gmail.com'
    licenseName = 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'
    licenseUrl = 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
    allLicenses = ["Apache-2.0"]
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0'
}

apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nuuneoi/JCenter/master/installv1.gradle'
apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nuuneoi/JCenter/master/bintrayv1.gradle'
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have files outside of the groupId in your pom file. You have  files under `library` [path](https://dl.bintray.com/hitanshu-dhawan/maven/com/hitanshudhawan/library/) and not under the `sharedpref` path.
There was also no metadata created under the `library` path.

You can check the [user manual](https://dl.bintray.com/hitanshu-dhawan/maven/com/hitanshudhawan/library/) for more information.

Comment: so what should i do ? @Royg
I have been struggling for days now without any luck.
Please help

Comment: It looks like your package was included to JCenter

Comment: For cleaner package on Bintray, I would remove the files from the `library` path ONLY. Be careful to delete only those files.

Comment: can you show me an example of bintray library...or a tutorial

Comment: See documentation: https://bintray.com/docs/usermanual/uploads/uploads_managinguploadedcontent.html#_deleting_content

Answer (score 0):

I have uploaded success 2 libraries to Bintray and JCenter, I wrote a guide how to do it, you can follow my guide to do it.

[Link library to bintray](https://github.com/tntkhang/library-to-bintray)